# Why does Tkinter wipe previous rectangles when drawing?

Tags: python, drawing, tkinter

When I draw a rectangle at global scope:

```
c = Canvas(width=IMAGE_WIDTH, height=IMAGE_HEIGHT, bg='black') 
c.create_rectangle([100, 100, 110, 110], fill='white')
c.pack()
root = Tk()
```

and follow this by drawing multiple rectangles in a loop

```
class gDrawer :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.rect_array = []
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def incr_counter(self,c,event=None): 
        one_pixel_loc = [self.x, self.y, self.x+5, self.y+5]
        self.rect_array.append(c.create_rectangle(one_pixel_loc, fill='white'))
        self.x += 1

gd = gDrawer()

for xx in range(100) :
    print xx
    gd.incr_counter(c)

root.mainloop()
```

The single drawn rectangle stays on the canvas while the loop drawn rectangle moves rather than creating a trail of rectangles. I'd like to draw a trail of rectangles and not a moving one, so what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default color for the outline of a `rectangle` is `black`.  This makes it seem like the other rectangles aren't being drawn when their outline is just overlapping.

Try changing:

```
self.rect_array.append(c.create_rectangle(one_pixel_loc, fill='white'))
```

to this:

```
self.rect_array.append(c.create_rectangle(one_pixel_loc, fill='white', outline='white')
```

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, hope it helps.

Comment: I want to have your babies! It did in fact turn out that because I was only shifting the "pixel" by less than the outline size every time I would redraw the next pixel it would cover the previous with the black outline.